# what is the quickest way of finding the set of all linearly independent sets over GF(2) and GF(3)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matroids, linear-independence

Here is the question I am trying to solve (note that in the textbook the columns are numbered from 1 to 6):

Let $A$ be the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
For $q$ in $\{2,3\},$ let $M_q[A]$ be the vector matroid of $A$ when $A$ is viewed over $GF(q),$ the field of $q$ elements. Show that:

$(a)$ The sets of circuits of $M_2[A]$ and $M_3[A]$ are different.

**Here are my thoughts:**

Since a minimal dependent set in an arbitrary $M$ is called a circuit of $M.$ Then I need to find all the independent sets with respect to both $GF(2)$ and $GF(3)$ and then the rest will be the set of dependent sets of this matroid and from which I can determine the set of minimal dependent sets.

My problem is:

what is the quickest way of finding the set of all linearly independent sets over GF(2) and GF(3)? should I use gaussian elimination but how?

My guess for the solution is since the columns $4,5$ and $6$ are linearly independent with respect to $GF(3)$ while they are linearly dependent with respect to $GF(2)$ then the set of circuits of $M_2[A]$ is different from the set of circuits of $M_3[A].$ Is my answer correct? Is it stated verbally correctly?

**Here is an answer to it I found on the internet (but I still not sure if it is correct or not)**

> [image]
> [image]

**Can someone verify if this answer is correct, or no? I do not see how the gauss elimination leads to these conclusions. **

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all material originally written by others.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing